# How to format LocalDate to yyyyMMDD (without JodaTime)

Tags: java

I am trying to get the date of the the next upcoming Friday and format it as yyyyMMDD. I would like to do this without using JodaTime if possible. Here is my code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

// snippet from main method
LocalDate friday = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('yyyyMMDD');
System.out.println(friday.format(formatter));
```

But when I run this I get the following error (running it today 20170809)

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Field DayOfYear cannot be printed as the value 223 exceeds the maximum print width of 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I am using Java 8

Comment: Do you mean `yyyyMMdd`? I'm sure you don't want to print day of year but day of month.

Comment: That is definitely what I meant. Today I learned.

Comment: `LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ).with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY ) ).format( DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE )`

Comment: For those using org.joda.time.LocalTime the solution would be friday.toString(ISODateTimeFormat.basicDate())

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Big `D` means `day-of-year`. You have to use small `d`.

So in your case use `"yyyyMMdd"`.

You can check all patterns [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

This particular pattern is built into Java 8 and later: [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE)

Answer (score 5):

I think you have two problems.

First, you are enclosing a String in character literals (`''` vs `""`).

Second, the `DD` (day of year) in your format string needs to be `dd` (day of month).

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: Ha, oops. Converted it from Groovy to Java for the sake of visibility. Thanks :)