# How to convert integer YYYYmmDD into YYYY/mm/DD in java

Tags: java, arrays, date, date-formatting, date-conversion

I am trying to process the data from a weather station. I simply want to process and print (for now) the minimum and maximum temperatures each day starting from 2000/01/01 until today 2019/12/12. The weather station gives me the date in an integer yyyymmdd like 20191212 or 20030317. I store this, alongside the minimum and maximum temperatures in an integer array, of about 21000 rows long... I want the date to be displayed in yyyy/mm/dd, like 2019/12/12 or 2003/03/17. How exactly do I go about doing this?

This is my code

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int rowAmount = 7152;   //the amount of rows in the document
        int[] temperatures = new int[rowAmount*3];  //makes an array 3 times the size of rowAmount, to fit date, min temp and max temp.
        try {   
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\20002019minmaxtempbilt.txt")); // Makes the filereader

            String fileRead = br.readLine(); // reads first like
            int counter = 0;    //sets a counter
            while (fileRead != null) { // loops until the file ends.
                String[] tokenize = fileRead.split(","); //splits the line in 3 segements, date, min temp and max temp. And stores them in following variables
                int tempDate = Integer.parseInt(tokenize[0]);
                int tempMin = Integer.parseInt(tokenize[1]);
                int tempMax = Integer.parseInt(tokenize[2]);
                //adds the values to the array
                temperatures[counter] = tempDate;
                counter++;
                temperatures[counter] = tempMin;
                counter++;
                temperatures[counter] = tempMax;
            }
            // close file stream
            br.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {
            System.out.println("file not found");
        }

        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Displays the entire array, formatted by date neatly, hopefully.

        for(int i = 0; i<rowAmount; i =+ 3) {
            int tempDate = temperatures[i];
            int tempMin = temperatures[i+1];
            int tempMax = temperatures[i+2];
            drawLine(tempDate, tempMin, tempMax);
        }


    }

    public static void drawLine(int tempDate, int tempMin, int tempMax) {
        /*This is where I get stuck. I need to convert tempDate from an int yyyymmdd to either
          3 separate integers representing year, month and day; or I need to convert it to a 
          string that can be printed out yyyy/mm/dd.*/

        System.out.printf("");

    }
}
```

Comment: For converting your integer to a `LocalDate` i posted [a new answer to one of the linked original questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59316435/5772882). How to format it is described in many places, for example [How to format LocalDate to yyyyMMDD (without JodaTime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598094/how-to-format-localdate-to-yyyymmdd-without-jodatime).

Comment: I recommend that rather than storing your numbers in adjacent cells of an array, you design a class with a `LocalDate` field and two fields for min and max temperaturs. Then store instances of this class into an array (or list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your date is a String to start with I see no reason to convert it to an Integer first. Using the more current java.time package you can use one formatter to convert from a String to LocalDate and then another to convert back to a String with the right format,

```
DateTimeFormatter inFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(tokenize[0], inFormatter);

DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
String outStr = outFormatter.format(date);
```

Since DateTimeFormatter is costly to initialise I would recommend you create both of them before the loop you have for reading the file.

Comment: There are more than one good point in this answer. Rather than using `Integer.parseInt(tokenize[0])` for converting your date from a string to a number, it’s better to parse it into a `LocalDate` from the outset. And yes, `LocalDate` from java.time is the good and correct class to use for dates.

Comment: If you need to convert from a `LocalDate` to an x or y coordinate in a plot/chart, I believe that `date.toEpochDay()` will give you a number that you can work with.

Answer (score 2):

Another way: if the integer value representing the date is stored in an int called `date` (example value: 20191212), then

```
  int day = date % 100;
  int month = (date/ 100) % 100;
  int year = date / 10000;
```

then you can use a Formatter to format the string output that you want.

Answer (score 1):

A problem is that an integer of 20191212 really doesn't represent a date.

I would recommend NOT transforming `tempDate` into an integer and leaving it as a string.

**Edit**

Here is an example that uses the [Java 8 time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes:  [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), and [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html):

package stackoverflow;

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

public class ParseStringDate {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        String dateString = "20191231";

        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatterParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");

        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateTimeFormatterParser);

        System.out.println(localDate);

        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatterPrinter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");

        System.out.println(localDate.format(dateTimeFormatterPrinter));

        dateTimeFormatterPrinter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("yyyy")
                .appendLiteral("/")
                .appendPattern("MM")
                .appendLiteral("/")
                .appendPattern("dd").toFormatter();

        System.out.println(localDate.format(dateTimeFormatterPrinter));
    }
}
```

Here is an example that uses `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormattingFromString {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        String tempDate = "20191212";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYmmdd");

        Date date = sdf1.parse(tempDate);

        // Now format the above date as needed...
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/mm/dd");

        System.out.println(sdf2.format(date));
    }
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, `SimpleDateFormat` and the `Date` classes are not super great to work with.  They are mutable and therefore not thread safe.  The new `java.time` package classes are immutable and therefore thread safe.  The new classes are also easier to do date math with and comparisons.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) object, taking advantage of the [parse(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) and [format(Date)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) methods.

Comment: I certainly recommend against it. `DateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` along with `LocalDate`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).